# How to record a route while a user is walking

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I am working on an app that need to record the route of the user. I only know how to record the starting point but I don't know how to do the rest. Please help.

My work:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> routeLatlng = new ArrayList<LatLng>();    
Location currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

routeLatlng.add(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()));
```

Comment: you need to repeat the same every 5 second and get the new location, store that in one array in sequence and that's it you have your app ready!

Comment: As @SrihariKaranth said. But use a location listener, which will invoke said method every time the user has moved far enough to make a difference, or enough time has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to overwrite the onLocationChanged method to record the route. It responses when the current location of the user is changed.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLocation) {
    routeLatlng.add(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()));
}
```